# Unable to connect to server ( postgres ) - GCP - Kubernetes

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

[image: )]

I want to connect to my `Postgres DB` . I use deployment `NodePort` IP for the host field and also data from config file :

```
data:
  POSTGRES_DB: postgresdb
  POSTGRES_PASSWORD: my_password
  POSTGRES_USER: postgresadmin
```

[image]

But I get error . What do I do wrong ? If you need more info - let me know .

Comment: @AndryRadkevich Are not you using a service of type `NodePort` or `LoadBalancer` or any other load balancer for your Postgres Deployment? If you do, then use proper hostname and port. It should work.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you are connected to your cluster through VPN (or direct connect), you can't access 10.121.8.109. It's a private IP address and only available for apps and services within you VPC.

You need to create public access for your node port service. Try `kubectl get service` to find out the External IP for your service. Then try to connect to your IP address from External IP.

Rather than using NodePort service, you are better off using Load Balancer type service which might give you better flexibility in managing this especially in a production env. But it will cost a little more Likelihood of an IP Address to change is high, but load balancer or ingress service would automatically manage this for you through a fixed DNS. So you need to weigh the pros and cons of using service type based on your workload.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I've changed my service type to LoadBalancer and it works. But next question is, should I use this external ip for my node js code connection? Or I have to do it another way?

Comment: It's best to use DNS where possible. Makes it easier to maintain, as ip addresses can change. Even better you use cloud SQL for this which supports postgres.